# Permanent circuit board jumper - I have a RTC chip that kills soldered battery before clock set

Tags: soldering, jumper

If I wave solder in the battery, it begins draining rapidly until the RTC chip (clock) is set. So I installed a jumper. Now I manufacture without the jumper, and then in the bed of nails testing, I set the clock and install the jumper before I package it and put it in stock. I never EVER want the jumper removed, but it is happening. Is there a way to make a lockable jumper or other ideas for a solution?

Comment: Why is the jumper being removed?

Comment: What is the RTC chip?  Is this a known behavior the manufacturer will admit exists and has no workaround?   What about socketing the battery so that it can be installed later (and eventually replaced)?  What about soldering a shunt?

Comment: It is being removed because they don't know what they are doing, and end up trying everything. They shouldn't

Comment: The RTC part from TI is BQ32002.

Comment: Maybe a battery socket would have been better now that we have this issue. I'm not sure about the cost difference. The plan is that it will last something like 100 years, so it would not need replacing. My favorite thing suggested is soldering a shunt, but that is an additional step soldering after a board has been complete verified on the bed of nails. Hence it should probably go back for a complete test again.

Comment: maybe there's something like a 2-contact connector for in-line measurements that is "normally" shorted unless something is inserted

Comment: The hundred years lifetime belief is surely mistaken.  There exist few batteries that would not *self discharge* within a decade irrespective of load.

Comment: Presumably you are referring to "The backup supply current is measured only after an initial power up. The device behavior is not ensured before the first power up" . Note that refers to *power up* not *programming* - so maybe what you need to do is power them on before shelving them for the late programming and test.

Comment: @ChrisStratton hm, there's suppliers that [claim 40 years of testable endurance](http://www.tadiranbat.com/is-a-40-year-battery-life-a-reality.html).

Comment: few != none, there's nothing here to suggest that an exotic battery type is being used, and such solutions often bring associated product challenges.

Comment: @ChrisStratton The datasheet does mention that device is first initialized after total power loss by applying main supply for at least 1ms after backup supply is connected.

Comment: What battery, and exactly how 'rapidly' is it drained? If the battery is wave-soldered in, how do you prevent the solder from shorting out the battery?

Comment: It is a button battery with attached thru-hole pins for soldering in.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I went to say that LiSOCl2 typically claims 30 years. I see Tadiran have upped the ante :-). || IF they can main tain the 0.7% loss / year that would give 50% capacity at 100 years, and 25% at 200 years. **IF** - which seems unlikely, but. || They say ". Due to very low self-discharge, Tadiran cells can survive accelerated testing for 90 months at 72°C (the equivalent of hundreds of years of continuous operation)."

Answer (score 1):

You could have a solder jumper land pattern that does not have solder on it normally (opposite side of board from wave soldering).  Only apply a solder bridge when required.  There are many land pattern designs out there if you google them.

Comment: I like this idea, too bad the ICT bed of nails can't solder.

Answer (score 1):

Could you wave solder in a battery holder instead, and install the battery later in your manufacturing process?

Here's an app note from TI about this sort of thing using their parts: https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/powerhouse/archive/2014/06/05/maximize-shelf-life-with-a-one-time-push-button-switch

Answer (score 1):

More ideas:

- conductive paint dabbed onto a SMD resistor footprint
- use a simple graphite pencil to shorten two pads (your RTC doesn't draw enough current, hopefully, to make these couple 100 Ω a problem)
- make through holes in the right distance. Use an office stapler to close the circuit
- big fat REMOVING THIS JUMPER DAMAGES THE DEVICE AND IS DETECTABLE silkscreen or neon sticker
- through-hole rivet

Answer (score 1):

You could add an inexpensive SOT-23 or SC-70 MOSFET and a (say) 10M resistor and put the jumper in place to turn the RTC off.

There would be a drain of a few hundred nA, probably less than the battery self-discharge, until the jumper is removed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frO9Qb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I suppose nobody make a discrete antifuse.  This idea however seems like something that could be opened automatically with a very low current conventional fuse, or else a through hole resistor or loop of wire that gets manually clipped off.

Comment: @ChrisStratton As far as I know, nobody makes one. The ["zener zap" method](http://downloads.hindawi.com/archive/1996/023706.pdf) is used in some chips for trimming, but I doubt OP wants to characterize ordinary parts for that.

Comment: An antifuse (great word) is what I was thinking. I was wondering if there existed something like that that would maybe arc over and make a connection when hit with a strong pulse of electricity. Something like you can buy to repair a string of Christmas lights; you put it into the string of lights, pull the trigger and if must fuse something in the light string to "repair" the string of lights.

Comment: I don't know of any discrete antifuse product. A quick test verifies that an LL4148 subjected to a 5A/5V (power supply settings) for about 0.5s will perform this function (also with some visible light indication- red LED?) but characterizing it for a production application, including reliability, would be non-trivial, to say the least, and you would have to ensure the "programming pulse" didn't screw  up the other circuitry.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find a wire wrap gun somewhere, you can make a permanent no-solder jumper (assuming the current jumper is a standard 0.1" square pin).

Answer (score 0):

The RTC datasheet says that after it has been totally unpowered, the device only needs the main supply shortly after connecting battery. Apply the main power to board just after manufacturing so it stops consuming battery, even if it is being tested later.

Comment: Might be tricky, because the datasheet says that Vcc initialization needs to be done _every_ time main power is lost. This seems painful enough on its own that I'd probably be shopping for a new RTC, myself...

Comment: No, it does not say that. VCC is tne main power. It says if all power has been lost, VCC initialization needs to happen by applying VCC for at least 1 millisecond after battery has been connected.

Comment: Section 8.2.2.3 of the datasheet says after "after every total power loss situation". I misspoke in my previous comment when I said every time "main power" was lost. I apologize.